# how to view individual field of the table in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I have created following table in mysql

[image]

I want to retrieve one of the field i.e abstract or author or Title by using id dynamically in view field. 
These are my model, controller and view code.
Model:This is my model

```
 $this->db->select("*"); 
               $this->db->limit(10);  
               $this->db->from("abcde");
     $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM abcde ORDER BY DocumentID ASC");
```

Controller: this is my controller here

```
 $this->load->model("Sample_model");  
              $data["fetch_data"] = $this->Sample_model->fetch_data();  
              $data['view']='services_view';
              $this->load->view('load_view', $data);
    return $query;
```

View:This is my view page

```
 <?php 

           if($fetch_data->num_rows() > 0)  
           {  
                foreach($fetch_data->result() as $row)  
                {  
           ?>  
                <tr>  

                     <td><?php echo $row->Abstract

                </tr>  
           <?php       
                }  
           }  

           ?>  
            </table>
```

The above view is displaying all the record of abstract.I want to use ID in view so  that i can get specific abstract in one line.

for example display abstract where id=1 or display author where id 3.Important point is here that i want to use id in view of the codeigniter. I will be grateful to you for your help.

Comment: how to use in codeigniter, i dont know.can you write the format

Comment: @pradeep answered your question it maybe works test it.

Comment: also you have an error in `$fetch_data->result()` change it to `$fetch_data->result_array()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

You can use `custom` helper to get the desired result

Add a file in your helpers folder name `custom_helper.php` and autoload with `autoload.php` like this :

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('custom');
```

In your `custom_helper.php` add a function like this :

```
function get_abstract($id)
{
   $ci = & get_instance();
   $query = $ci->db->get_where('abcde',['id' => $id]); 
   return $query->row()->abstract;   
}
```

in your view call this `get_abstract` function like this:

```
   <?php 

    if($fetch_data->num_rows() > 0)  
    {  
        foreach($fetch_data->result() as $row)  
        {  
    ?>  
        <tr>  
            <!-- get abstract by id like this -->
            <td><?php echo get_abstract($row->id);?></td>
        </tr>  
  <?php }  
}?>
```

**Update** : your controller should be like this :

```
public function services() 
{ 
    $this->load->model("Sample_model"); 
    $data["fetch_data"] = $this->Sample_model->fetch_data(); 
    $data['view']='services_view'; 
    $this->load->view('load_view', $data); 
}
```

Your model `fetch_data` should be like this :

```
function fetch_data() 
{ 
    $this->db->order_by("DocumentID" ,"ASC");
    $this->db->limit(1);  
    $query = $this->db->get('prlaps');
    return $query; 
}
```

**Update** for View with using `row()` instead of `result()`:

```
<?php 
if($fetch_data->num_rows() > 0)  
{  
    $row = $fetch_data->row();    
    echo get_abstract($row->id);
}?>
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'abcde'

SELECT * FROM `abcde`, `abcde` WHERE `id` IS NULL

Filename: helpers/custom_helper.php
Line Number: 6

Comment: show your controller , how you r retrieving all data for the view  pls show  . the error is just because may be the id column is incorrect show me the correct field name for id

Comment: public function services()
        {
          $this->load->model("Sample_model");  
          $data["fetch_data"] = $this->Sample_model->fetch_data();  
          $data['view']='services_view';
          $this->load->view('load_view', $data);
        }

Comment: show me model method `fetch_data` from this `$this->Sample_model->fetch_data();`

Comment: function fetch_data()  
        {  
          
        
           $this->db->select("*"); 
           $this->db->from("prlaps");
        
           $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM prlaps ORDER BY DocumentID ASC");  
         

           return $query; 

         }

Comment: prlaps is table name----but in question i changed it as abcde, id as DocumentID

Comment: is your DocumentID is the correct id if not pls replace it with your correct id

Comment: i have updated my answer for controller and model pls check model and controller

Comment: it is giving all the abstract of the table.How to display only one in view by changing id in view

Comment: In view -<?php echo get_abstract($row->id=3);?> is giving correct abstract but 7 times i.e. number of rows in the table.How to stop this loop so that i can get only one time

Comment: ok just add limit to 1 to your model  `fetch_data`  like this `$this->db->limit(1);`  see my updated answer, or better return `row()` instead or `result()` in view

Comment: it is given you 7 times just because you have total number of records in `prlaps` table is 7

Comment: Your first answer has solved my problem. But row() option is again giving error A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property 'DocumentID' of non-object

Comment: this is because if you use `row()` no need of `foreach` loop  there

Comment: can you write the exact code using row() also.This will be useful

Comment: see my updated answer in the last, by the way if my answer helps you pls do upvote and accept my answer